# Caesar cipher encoding in C++: chars won't loop back to 'a' or 'A'

Tags: c++, caesar-cipher

I'm working on coding a ceasar cipher that reads plaintext from a .txt, encrypts the plaintext and writes to a second .txt, then reads the second .txt and decrypts it to a third .txt. Everything is working except the encryption of characters near the end of the alphabet. When a character reaches 'z' or 'Z' it should loop back to 'a' or 'A'. Below is a snippet of code from my encoding function, this is the only bit that's causing issues.

```
if (isalpha(inputString[i])) {         //use isalpha() to ignore other characters
    for (int k = 0; k < key; k++) {     //key is calculated in another function, 6 in this case
        if (inputString[i] == 'z')      //these statements don't seem to work
            encryptedString[i] = 'a';
        else if (inputString[i] == 'Z')
            encryptedString[i] = 'A';
        else                            //this part works correctly
            encryptedString[i] ++;
    }               
}
```

Input:

THE quick brown fox

Jumped over the----

House or moon or some-thing.

Expected output:

ZNK waoiq hxuct lud

Pasvkj ubkx znk----

Nuayk ux suut ux yusk-znotm.

Actual Output:

THE q{ick bro}n fo~

J{mped o|er the----

Ho{se or moon or some-thing.

Key: 6

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: There's probably a bug somewhere in your code. If you showed us, we might be able to find it. IOW, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If I remember correctly caesar cipher is simply adding the key and modulo the number of letters in the alphabet. So you can do `ciphered[i] = (input[i] + key)  % ('z' - 'a') + 'a'`

Comment: @ZivS you need an "offset" as well, `+'a'`. Otherwise it won't be valid ascii.

Comment: @Jonas, yes just fixed it...

Comment: @ZivS you could post it as an answer, it is more efficient that the original loop based approach.

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to give these answers on SO. I thought twice about posting code in the comment. simply suggesting an alternative like: "you can use modulo calculus to solve this" is enough, this is a simple homework question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying `encryptedString` and then basing your "loop-over" decision on `inputString`.

I suspect that you want to firstly initialize `encryptedString` from `inputString`, and then work only on `encryptedString`.
It looks, to me, like you should do it like this:

```
encryptedString[i] = inputString[i]; // initialize encryptedString
if (isalpha(inputString[i]))
{
    for (int k = 0; k < key; k++)
    {
        if (encryptedString[i] == 'z') // read from encryptedString instead of inputString
            encryptedString[i] = 'a';
        else if (encryptedString[i] == 'Z') // read from encryptedString instead of inputString
            encryptedString[i] = 'A';
        else
            encryptedString[i] ++;
    }               
}
```

Comment: Changing from input to encrypted string fixed it. I did set encryptedString = inputString earlier in the code (right after I pulled the line from the txt file).